# how does git use permissions it has for blobs and trees

Tags: git

If I do `git ls-tree branchname path/to/directory` I get the following output:

```
100644 blob d7cf85396913fb7169a881d8334f32af153122eb    .gitignore
100644 blob ba7adb479be66d8f1d62384ab53997cddd465110    .travis.yml
040000 tree 2de254bbec97958db2375e2d0ab767b23315ab50    application
```

So I'm seeing the following permissions set:

```
100644 for blobs, 040000 for trees
```

From what I've read 100644 can be interpreted like - `regular file with sticky bit of 0 and file permissions of 644 (not executable by anyone)`, `040000` - `directory with sticky bit of 0 and no permissions`. Instead of `644` for blob, `755` is also possible since I've read `git` tracks only executable bits.

My question is how exactly does `git` use these permissions? Does it apply them to files and folders in working tree when checking out branch? Or does it use them internally somehow?

PS. Please note, this question is NOT about what those permissions stand for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git uses these permission to determine the type of a directory entry on checkout and to set the execute permission flag if necessary. As far as I know, they are not used in any other way.

In git, there are fewer file modes than in a standard posix file system:

- 100644: normal files
- 100755: executable files
- 040000: directories
- 120000: symlinks

Comment: Without reference, this hardly qualifies as a complete answer; it would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: @Jubobos I know, but I didn't find any official references. There's documentation for [`git update-index`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) updating the permissions in the repo, but nothing mentioning the check-out phase.

Comment: @Yogu, thanks! So how come I can get inside directories if the permissions for directories is 000?

Comment: @Maximus: Directories only have one file mode in git, and that's 040000 by definition. The executable bit is not stored in the repository for directories.

Comment: @Yogu, I'm thinking that if git stores permissions for folders as `000`, and if it sets the same permission for folder when checked out, how the folder will be accesible then?

Comment: @Maximus It only uses the execute bit for files, the directory permission is not affected by the bits stored in the repository at all.

Comment: @Yogu, aha, thanks, so what permissions does it set for a folder when it checks it out? 777 ? Or is it somehow determined by OS using UMASK of the user the git is running under?

Comment: It uses the [umask config](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for permissions.